# 1 Solution, 2 Proejcts, 2 Web.Configs?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have an ASP.net solution that includes 2 projects.  One of them is basically a class library and the other is a web service that references the class library.

I want the library to use a web.config to access global connection strings yet I want the library to be able to function independently of the service.  There is a web.config file in the web service project that both the library and the service are currently using.  How can I create a separate config file inside the library project so it doesn't have to access the one inside the service?  It seems I am able to simply create a new web.config file under the Library but I can't figure out how to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the `Project -> Settings` which in turn creates an app.config file for your use?

I'm using the Web.config file for all User Interface (UI) information, and I use the app.config in the core project (Class Library) to store the encrypted connection string as well as other "settings" used by the core project.